# Every array of enum implements IEnumerable<EveryOtherEnum>. How do I work around this?

Tags: c#, .net, types, enums

It appears that, in .NET, "array of enum" is not a strongly-typed concept. `MyEnum[]` is considered to implement not just `IEnumerable<MyEnum>`, but also `IEnumerable<YourEnum>`. (I didn't believe it at first either.)

```
// Returns true:
typeof(IEnumerable<DayOfWeek>).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(AttributeTargets[]))

// Outputs "3":
var listOfLists = new List<object> {
    new[] { AttributeTargets.All },
    new[] { ConsoleColor.Blue },
    new[] { PlatformID.Xbox, PlatformID.MacOSX }
};
Console.WriteLine(listOfLists.OfType<IEnumerable<DayOfWeek>>().Count());
```

So when I go looking through a list for everything that implements `IEnumerable<T>`, I'm getting the `T[]`s and the `List<T>`s and the iterator-generated `IEnumerable<T>`s, but I'm also getting the `SomethingElse[]`s that I do not want.

What's the easiest way to find out whether a given `Type` (as with IsAssignableFrom above) or a given instance (as with `OfType<T>` above) *really and truly* implements, say, `IEnumerable<DayOfWeek>`?

---

I gave Mr. Skeet the green checkmark, but once I got his code into Visual Studio, ReSharper suggested a more concise version. Use whichever version you prefer.

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> OfSequenceType<T>
    (this IEnumerable source) where T : struct
{
    return from sequence in source.OfType<IEnumerable<T>>()
           let type = sequence.GetType()
           where !type.IsArray || type.GetElementType() == typeof (T)
           select sequence;
}
```

Comment: +1 that's an interesting corner case. Paging doctor Skeet... Paging doctor Skeet :)

Comment: Great question... hope you enjoy spec-diving :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe this is basically due to section 8.7 of [ECMA 335](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-335.htm).

Basically we're looking at the *assignable-to* relationship between the two array-of-enum types. As far as I can tell, 8.7.2 is applicable:

> A location type T is compatible-with a location type U if and only if one of the following holds.
>
> 1. T and U are not managed pointer types and T is *compatible-with* U according to the definition in §8.7.1.

So we look to 8.7.1 and find bullet 5:

> T is a zero-based rank-1 array V[], and U is a zero-based rank-1 array W[], and V is *array-element-compatible-with* W.

So now we're interested in whether the two enum types have an *array-element-compatible-with* relationship... That then leads to:

> A signature type T is array-element-compatible-with a signature type U if and only if T has underlying type V and U has underlying type W and either:
>
> 1. V is compatible-with W; or
> 2. V and W have the same reduced type.

Now the *underlying type* of an enum is defined by this:

> The *underlying type* of a type T is the following:
>
> 1. If T is an enumeration type, then its underlying type is the underlying type declared in the enumeration‘s definition.
> 2. [Irrelevant to us]

So in the case of, say:

```
enum Foo : int {}
enum Bar : int {}
```

the underlying types of both are `int`.

Now we can go back to our *array-element-compatible-with* definition, and see that both V and W are `int`. A type is *compatible-with* itself due to the first bullet of 8.7.1:

> A signature type T is compatible-with a signature type U if and only if at least one of the following holds.
>
> 1. T is identical to U.

Therefore, the arrays are compatible.

They're also compatible with an array of the underlying type itself:

```
enum Foo {}
...
object x = new int[10];
Foo[] y = (Foo[]) x; // No exception
```

Note that `x` has to be declared as `object` here to persuade the C# compiler that this *might* be legal - otherwise it follows the rules of the C# language, which aren't quite so forgiving...

---

Now as for your second question:

> What's the easiest way to find out whether a given Type (as with IsAssignableFrom above) or a given instance (as with OfType above) really and truly implements, say, IEnumerable?

You *could* just special case arrays, as they behave a little oddly. Frankly that's probably the easiest approach. I tried using [`Type.GetInterfaceMap`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getinterfacemap.aspx) but that gives a problem too:

> Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentException: Interface maps for generic interf
>   aces on arrays cannot be retrived.

(Yes, the typo at the end is really in the error message. Can't be bothered to raise a Connect issue for that though...)

I strongly suspect that special-casing is the way forward... for example, assuming that you *know* you're dealing with a value type (covariance of reference type arrays is a separate matter...)

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> OfSequenceType<T>
    (this IEnumerable source) where T : struct
{
    // Nullity check elided...
    foreach (object x in source)
    {
        IEnumerable<T> sequence = x as IEnumerable<T>;
        if (sequence == null)
        {
            continue;
        }
        // Work around odd value type array variance
        Type type = sequence.GetType();
        if (type.IsArray && type.GetElementType() != typeof(T))
        {
            continue;
        }
        yield return sequence;
    }
}
```

Comment: So that answers *why* it does this. (I figured it was something of the sort, probably for compatibility with Java.) But it doesn't help me figure out how to work around it...

Comment: That's where I was starting to head, inspired by GianT971's idea of checking for the array type explicitly. Your code is much cleaner than what I was coming up with, though!

Comment: @JoeWhite: I didn't mention it, but it's *completely* untested. Hope it works for you :)

Comment: Should the first `if` be `if (sequence == null)` rather than `if (x == null)`?

Comment: @JonSkeet it is continue and not break

Comment: @GianT971 is right -- both places should be continue instead of break.

Comment: Thanks to both of you - yes indeed. This is the problem with writing untested code at near-midnight :)

Comment: It's tested code now. (grin) I edited in the corrections noted here in the comments, and it seems to be working well. Thanks for a great starting point!

Answer (score 1):

I tried this:

```
var listOfLists = new List<object> {
    new[] { AttributeTargets.All },
    new[] { ConsoleColor.Blue },
    new[] { PlatformID.Xbox, PlatformID.MacOSX },
    new[] { DayOfWeek.Friday, DayOfWeek.Saturday }
};
Console.WriteLine(listOfLists.Where(obj => obj.GetType() == typeof(DayOfWeek[])).Count());
```

I got 1 as a result. I'm still searching to see how you can use IEnumerable< DayOfWeek > in the query

Comment: Using `OfType<>` isn't the same as checking for equality with `GetType()`.

Comment: This inspired me to start to come up with a solution, based on checking the type explicitly if it's an Array. Looks like Mr. Skeet beat you (and me) to posting working code, though.

Comment: Ok, yeah it seems so :) but I don't manage to have his code work? Console.WriteLine(listOfLists.OfSequenceType<DayOfWeek>().Count()) outputs 0, even though I added a List<DayOfWeek> in the listOfLists

Comment: He made a mistake, using break instead of continue